Where do I clear immigration London to Mumbai to Chennai?
I'm traveling to Chennai from London Heathrow, with a transit in Mumbai. The layover time is exactly 2 hours. Where will my immigration counter be?

What’s your flight company from Mumbai ?

Is your question about which airport you will be clearing immigration at, or where in the airport immigration is?

You will have to pass through immigration in Mumbai and transit domestically, since the flight to Chennai is going to be a domestic flight from Mumbai. So your passport will be checked at Mumbai.

And at Heathrow!

@phoog 'from London Heathrow': there is no (standard) UK exit control, only entry control.

@MarkJohnson However, the airline will almost certainly check the passport either before issuing a boarding pass or before letting the OP board the plane, so the statement is technically still correct.

@MarkJohnson I mixed up "from" and "to" when I read the question.  It seems more natural to me to say "going from A to B" than "going to B from A," so I read it wrong.

@AustinHemmelgarn a passport check at check-in is not "clearing immigration" in the sense in which that term is most commonly used.

On Heathrow -> Mumbai -> Chennai
You will have to clear immigration at Mumbai. Your bags usually gets checked through and you can collect in Chennai, depends on the airline. You can inquire about that in Heathrow.
On Chennai -> Mumbai -> Heathrow
Your documents will be verified in Chennai itself. You will receive two boarding passes (Chennai -> Mumbai, Mumbai -> London). When you reach Mumbai, you go through international transfer and clear emigration at Mumbai. Your bags will be checked through and you won't need to collect bags.
Exception
I once traveled on an Air India flight from Singapore, which stopped on Madurai, India and de boarded passengers traveling to Madurai and the same plane proceeded to Kochi, India. I had to clear immigration at Kochi only. But this is a very rare case.

Bags would have to collected in Mumbai to pass through customs channels and then resubmitted. One can't skip customs just by having an onward domestic flight. Many people on BOM-MAA flight would not be connecting from internation flights don't pass through customs at MAA. (Exception is of course the rare stopover flights like the one you have mentioned).

@ThomasCruise It will go through customs. Not sure if mannual intervention is needed. I haven't traveled in International -> Domestic -> Domestic segment.

Manual intervention is needed - much like the US there are baggage re-check desks if you turn left just after customs.

The traveler has to go tbrough customs along with everything they are carrying. It is not just checked luggage. There is handbag, pockets, jewelry, taped contraband, swallowed contraband etc (of course that is not checked for most but still). Booking a domestic connection is not a loophole to skip customs. Major airlines like Air India and Vistara have transfer desks so one doesn't has to exit and re-enter to doemstic departures if it is a single e-ticket.
